# docker-compose scale service with independent volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to write a compose-file using a service (node) that I'd like to scale to 3 containers. This service has a volume to be bond to my local system for persistence, but I'd like the different tasks having different binding on my system ? I tried to use the template `{{.Task.Slot}}` inside my docker-compose.yml as shown below, but I cannot figured out out to make it work...

```
version: '3.2'
services:
     node:
        build:
            context: ./node
        volumes:
            - nodeVol:/data
        command: ["myapp"]

volumes:
    nodeVol:
        external:
            name: './persistence/{{.Task.Slot}}'
```

Any idea of what went wrong ?

Comment: Have you seen any documentation suggesting that a template like that would work? I would suggest using a single volume, and then have each container instance create a subdirectory at runtime.

Comment: I've seen this kind of solution in another forum, but they used docker swarm and not docker-compose. Thank you for your reply, but the problem remains: if I want every instance of my service having it's own directory, I should be able to differentiate them. I can still use the HOSTNAME variable, but every time I stop the services and then relaunch them, a new directory will be created. One solution could be to retrieve the instance of the service that is running, but cannot figure out how to do that ...

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751495/using-task-slot-in-docker-volumes