# Using {{.Task.Slot}} in Docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I would like to mount individual volumes to each replica of my Docker service using the `{{.Task.Slot}}` syntax:

```
services:
  foo:
    ...
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: foo{{.Task.Slot}}
        target: /mnt
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3

volumes:
  foo1:
    ...
  foo2:
    ...
  foo3:
    ...
```

However, Docker fails with:

```
service foo: undefined volume "foo{{.Task.Slot}}"
```

It seems that the Go syntax is not interpreted in the `source` property but in the `target` property, it works smoothly:

```
services:
  foo:
    ...
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: foo1
        target: /mnt{{.Task.Slot}}
```

But that's obviously not what I need.

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30770) help at all? I don't have the time to test it out immediately.

Comment: Amazing. It actually does! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it:

```
services:
  foo:
    ...
    volumes:
      - foo:/mnt
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 3

volumes:
  foo:
    name: 'foo-{{.Task.Slot}}'
    ...
```

Scaling the service will then create the volume(s) as needed.

All credits go to @larsks.